# Looking for a lead in order to link funnel dropouts and with website bugs

Tags: website-design, subscription

i am trying to analyze customer experience from a different perspective: killer bugs and website bugs in general.

I am struggling to find practices and/or literature on the subject. I'd like to use data logs and funnel analysis to find if there is a correlation between dropouts and bugs on the website (i'm pretty sure there is).
Is there anyone that can point me to a book, a whitepaper or something to better understand how i can approach this matter? Also if you can point me to a different and more appropriate board that's okay.
The context is onboarding and subscription of financial services, but at this level is not much relevant.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

What are "killer bugs", if you use your own novel terminology you will definitely have trouble finding existing literature regarding it.

Correlation of logs as part of root cause analysis is a daily activity of IT operations and development teams. You may find people and tooling used by such teams help you. I often setup analytics events that log problem scenarios so as to monitor potential problems or even smarts that can affect the customer, providing greater insight into the system's usage by users. Real-Time User Monitoring (RUM), such as Stream View in Firebase Analytics can provide great insight into usage that encounters problems (as long as you are logging the problems too).

I would expect ad-hoc surveying of users (recent users) to be a great way to determine whether bugs were actually a major factor in a user's reason for abandoning your system. You might find that without the bugs, the users aren't fond of the `fandangled thing that was being attempted that caused the bugs in the first place` or even the slow load speed caused by attempts to wow the user.

Root-cause analysis:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis
https://blog.overops.com/why-root-cause-analysis-is-important-for-it-ops-and-how-to-do-it/

Drop-off triggered by increased security constraints: https://edgardunn.com/2020/03/from-hard-decline-to-abandoned-purchases-conversion-killers-in-the-new-era-of-ecommerce-payment-security/